# TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' について

Tags: python

https://qiita.com/rrryutaro/items/10142d3c3397406e5e2b
このサイトを参考にしてコードを打ったのですが、エラーが出てしまいました。どなたかわかる方がいたら教えてください。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hoge.py", line 10, in <module>
    img1_2 = img1[162:162+14, 467:467+32]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

今度は別のエラーが出てしまいました。

```
/Users/xxxxx/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:3118: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice. out=out, **kwargs)
/Users/xxxxx/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:85: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount) nan nan
```

Comment: この記事が参考になるかも。[pythonでAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hoge'が発生してしまう。](https://teratail.com/questions/97976)

Comment: このエラーは出なくなりましたが、今度は別のエラーが出てしまいました。`/Users/xxxxx/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:3118: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  out=out, **kwargs)
/Users/xxxxx/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:85: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
nan
nan`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

参考にした記事のひとつ前の記事に書いてありますが、そこで使っているPythonは 3.6.0 です。
[(2017年12月) PythonとOpenCVをこれからやってみる - 1 - はじめの一歩](https://qiita.com/rrryutaro/items/4c40873d6b06096cfe93)

```
コマンドプロンプト
> python -V
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)
```

エラーメッセージでは使っているPythonが 2.7 のようなので、版数が違うせいで色々と問題が発生している可能性があります。
最低限、記事で使っている版数の系統(2.x/3.xの違い)に合わせましょう。
ただし、記事自体も2年以上前で、最新版はもっと版数が進んでいますので注意は必要です。